# How fetch data from one database and another data from another database in same field

Tags: php, html, mysqli, bootstrap-4

I want to fetch records from database in category field with a button next to it, and when I click on that button there is a bootstrap collapse on which I have to display records from another database which is the sub-category of that specific category field and it should dynamically fetch the records as per above category field., and will be keep on changing when changes done from admin side. I want to write PHP code in SQL query, below code shows no error but does not provides me the expected outcome. Please Help me friends.

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","zuuvee");
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM category_name");
$query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM subcategory_name WHERE category = 'Apparel & Accessories'");


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Category</title>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
{
?>
<ul>
<li>
  <span class="number"><?php echo $row['ID']; ?></span>
  <span><a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#third<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" aria-expanded="false"></a>
  <span><label name ="lb1"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></label></span>
  <div class="collapse" id="third<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">

            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
              <?php
  while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) 
  {
  ?>
    <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $row1['subcategory']; ?></h5> 
      <?php
        }
        ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div></span>

  <span class="points">00</span>
  <span class="badge"><i class= "fa fa-microchip" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>


      </li>
    </ul>
  <?php
    }
    ?>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: get the `ul` tag outside of the loop, and the closing after the loop

Comment: @M0ns1f Thank you so much!! That was really helpful. Will you please help more, how should am I suppose to fetch the records from another database of subcategory in specific field of category? (record is dynamic, I guess we have to use PHP code in SQL query.)

Comment: Guys need help.